# Using R package in Java

Tags: java, r

I have a R package .Can it be implemented if i am running R in java

Comment: Check JRI for a Java/R interface. https://rforge.net/JRI/

Comment: we can implement inbuilt function of R but i wanna know if we can implement a R package with it in java